# How to select a set of data from a column in DataFrame with specific condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, data-science

Please find the below  columnn data , I want to select the entire data where Column DISC does not contain the value AA in it .  In the below data , I want to display the data of JOSE , YEN and REX.

> Name   ---------Disc  --------            Class
> GINA     ------ -     AA BB CC  -----            10
> JOSE ------      -      TT YY  ----- ----            10
> TOM    ------- -       AA TT           ----------     15
> YEN       --------    HH UJ II --------      15
> REX       -----------       KK    -------------             15

How can I select the data?
The value 'AA BB CC' is a string and has white spaces in between .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```py
df[~df['Disc'].str.contains('AA')]
```

The operand `~` simply negates the `True-False` array returned by `df['Disc'].str.contains('AA')`, which gives you rows where `Disc` does not contain `'AA'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas.Series.str.find](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and find row labels(index) that contain 'AA'.

```
import pandas as pd 

# initialized data of lists. 
data = {'Name':['GINA', 'JOSE', 'TOM','YEN','REX'],
        'Disc':['AA BB CC', 'TT YY', 'AA TT', 'HH UJ II','KK'],                    
        'Class':[10, 10, 15, 15,15]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# substring to be searched 
sub ='AA'

#If it finds 'AA' in the Disc column, it returns 0, and otherwise returns -1
ResultSearch=df["Disc"].str.find(sub)
#find index of dataframe that contain 'AA'
AA_index=[i for i in range(len(ResultSearch)) if(ResultSearch[i]==0)]

df_copy = df.copy()
df_copy.drop(AA_index,inplace=True)
print(df)
print(df_copy)
```

output:

```
   Name      Disc  Class
0  GINA  AA BB CC     10
1  JOSE     TT YY     10
2   TOM     AA TT     15
3   YEN  HH UJ II     15
4   REX        KK     15
```

---

```
   Name      Disc  Class
1  JOSE     TT YY     10
3   YEN  HH UJ II     15
4   REX        KK     15
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your substring is **always** in the beginning of
the string, you could use [.startswith()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html?highlight=starts#pandas.Series.str.startswith) method, something like this:

```
df = df[~(df['Disc'].str.startswith('AA'))]
```

Output:

```
   Name      Disc  Class
1  JOSE     TT YY     10
3   YEN  HH UJ II     15
4   REX        KK     15
```